# Relative paths do not work in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: kotlin, relative-path

I am having a problem with relative paths in my Kotlin/JavaFX (Intellij IDEA) project.
If I try to load a file, using an absolut path it works fine, as soon as I am trying the same with a relative, it does not work. I checked everything, spelling etc. I created a test class in the same package and it still could not load the file. I figured something was wrong and tried the same in an empty project, without gradle/javafx and i could load Files using relative paths. Is there something wrong with my project configuration?

```
stage.icons.add(Image("C:\\Users\\nicol\\spz_app\\dev\\app\\spz\\Spz\\src\\main\\resources\\org\\nico\\spz\\logo.png")); // works
```

```
val test = SpzApplication::class.java.getResource("Test.txt")
println(test.toExternalForm("Spz/src/main/resources/org/nico/spz/logo.png")) //does not work

val test = SpzApplication::class.java.getResource("Test.txt")
println(test.toExternalForm("Test.txt")) //does not work as well even though there is a Text.txt file in the same package
```

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'application'
  id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.8.10'
  id 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin' version '1.8.12'
  id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.13'
  id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.25.0'
}

group 'org.nico'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

ext {
  junitVersion = '5.9.2'
}

sourceCompatibility = '17'
targetCompatibility = '17'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
  options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

application {
  mainModule = 'org.nico.spz'
  mainClass = 'org.nico.spz.SpzApplication'
}

[compileKotlin, compileTestKotlin].forEach {
  it.kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '17'  }
}

javafx {
  version = '17.0.6'
  modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}



dependencies {
  implementation('org.controlsfx:controlsfx:11.1.2')
  implementation 'com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc11:21.1.0.0'
  implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.28'
  implementation 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:2.0'
  testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
  testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
  implementation 'org.jfxtras:jmetro:11.6.14'
  implementation 'io.github.palexdev:materialfx:11.16.1'
  implementation "joda-time:joda-time:2.10.10"
}

test {
  useJUnitPlatform()  }

sourceSets {
  main {
    resources {
      srcDirs = ['Spz/src/main/resources']
    }
  }
}

jlink {
  imageZip = project.file("${buildDir}/distributions/app-${javafx.platform.classifier}.zip")
  options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
  launcher {
    name = 'app'
  }
}

jlinkZip {
  group = 'distribution'
}
```

Comment: (1) Read the docs for `getResource(..)` you will see that this loads the sources from the Classpath which is not the same as the file system.  Sure the resource might be on the file system, but that will get compiled into the jar (=compiled code), so paths for classpath resources are relative to the top of the compiled resources location.  (2) show in your Question the file structure of your application e.g. using this tool: https://superuser.com/a/1303475 to get better help